# T24 routine - compilation error - No component defined. $PACKAGE is mandatory?

Tags: eclipse, jbase

Below is the sample code

```
SUBROUTINE HELLO.WORLD
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Modification History :
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

CRT "HELLO WORLD"

END
```

Compilation error;

```
01/01/2019 16:26:03 Compiling HELLO.WORLD...                    ERROR
     Error : (line 12) HELLO.WORLD.b, No component defined. $PACKAGE is mandatory !
Compilation completed for 1 file(s). 1 error
01/01/2019 16:26:03 Compiling HELLO.WORLD...                    ERROR
     Error : (line 12) HELLO.WORLD.b, No component defined. $PACKAGE is mandatory !
Compilation completed for 1 file(s). 1 error
```

I have setup (during toggle tafj project nature option in design studio);

- The TAFJ_HOME correctly.
- T24lib directory under "Known Libraries" section.
- Java folder : ....\ProjectName-models\java.
- Class folder : ....\ProjectName-models\classes.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To switch off this check for tCompile, set these properties in tafj.properties:

```
temn.tafj.compiler.internal.development=false
temn.tafj.compiler.component.strict.mode=false
```

However, to follow the "best practice way" you should have the $PACKAGE statement, then your JBC code will be compiled into a proper Java Package and put inside a JAR file. Note that before that you should do "New-->T24Component Folder Structure" in T24 Design Studio. This will create the XX.componentname.component file where you can define the subroutines. This "XX.Local.component" has to be compiled first:

```
component XX.Local
# Component Isolation Definition
metamodelVersion 1.6
# -------------------------------------------------

public method helloWorld ()
{
    jBC: HELLO.WORLD
}
```

Then you can reference the $PACKAGE in the subroutine like this:

```
$PACKAGE XX.Local
SUBROUTINE HELLO.WORLD
    CRT 'Hello, World!'
RETURN
END
```

The component can also be created manually without Design Studio. You should not use the Dunce Cap (see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce) unless you have a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project source folder and click “Put on / Take off the Dunce cap”. Compile again.

[image]

Comment: I tried to use this feature. Though I couldn't find the option in the right click menu. What is the design studio version you are using? (I am trying with R19)

Comment: Iam using R18 and I have the option in right click menu. It seems the dunce cap feature removed in R19 (TAFJ eclipse document). Try using the component feature.

Answer (score 0):

For R19 Right Click on project navigate to Properties->TAFJ->Compiler->Uncheck Maintain validation code.

Answer (score -1):

It's a subroutine , it needs a RETURN statement

Comment: Wrong answer, T24 soubroutine will compile without return statements.